# Updating data of QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, c++11, qt-creator

I populated a QTreeWidget with some data.The first column of each row is an integer value. When I press delete on a selected Item I would like that item to disappear and the numbers after the deleted item to decrease with 1. For example if I have 5 items in my first column I have the labels 1,2,3,4,5. When I delete item 3 for example I would like my new labels to be 1,2,3,4. Now my labels are 1,2,4,5.I have tried several things but did not find a good solution... My code is given bellow

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Delete)
    {
        QTreeWidgetItem *item = this->ui->testResultsTW->currentItem();
        if(!item)return;
        int x = this->ui->testResultsTW->indexOfTopLevelItem(item);
        if(x >= 0 && x < this->ui->testResultsTW->topLevelItemCount())
        {
            item = this->ui->testResultsTW->takeTopLevelItem(x);
            if(item)
           {
                delete item;
                stringstream ss;
                ss << (x + 1);
                string message = "Item " + ss.str() + " has been deleted";
                QTreeWidgetItem *item2;                   
              for(int i = x; i <= this->ui->testResultsTW->topLevelItemCount() ; i++)
              {

                   item2 = this->ui->testResultsTW->takeTopLevelItem(i);
                ss << (i - 1);
                string nr = ss.str();
                item2->data(0,Qt::UserRole) = nr;

                // item2->data(0,Qt::UserRole) = nr.c_str();
              //  item2->setText(0,tr("Ana"));
            }

            QMessageBox::information(this,"Deleted",message.c_str());

        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the text on the column 0 manually.

```
if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Delete)
    {
        QTreeWidgetItem *item = this->ui->testResultsTW->currentItem();
        if(!item)return;
        int x = this->ui->testResultsTW->indexOfTopLevelItem(item);
        if(x >= 0 && x < this->ui->testResultsTW->topLevelItemCount())
        {
            item = this->ui->testResultsTW->takeTopLevelItem(x);
            if(item)
            {
                delete item;
                stringstream ss;
                ss << (x + 1);
                string message = "Item " + ss.str() + " has been deleted";
                for(int i = x; i <= this->ui->testResultsTW->topLevelItemCount() ; i++)
                {
                    QTreeWidgetItem *topItem = this->ui->topLevelItem(i);
                    if(topItem) 
                    {
                        topItem->setText(0, QString::number(i + 1));
                    }
                }

            QMessageBox::information(this,"Deleted",message.c_str());

            }
        }
    }
```

Another question is :

```
item2 = this->ui->testResultsTW->takeTopLevelItem(i);
```

This code is remove item from the tree view, do you really want to remove it?

Comment: Thank you Apin! No I did not want to remove the element. Your answer solved my issue